# Eliminar registro de tabla

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

Tengo una tabla con varios posts y al lado de cada uno hay tres enlaces: mostrar, editar y eliminar. Al principio hay un enlace para crear un nuevo post.

Todo funciona correctamente a excepción del enlace eliminar que en vez de hacer su función, que es la de eliminar el correspondiente registro, se dirige a la vista de mostrar.

En este momento entiendo que al hacer clic en el enlace eliminar este debería mostrar un mensaje y al confirmar se debería ejecutar el método destroy del controlador que es el encargado de eliminar el registro para posteriormente redirigir a la vista de todos los posts

Archivo de rutas:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
  get 'posts/new'
  post "posts" => "posts#create"

  get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show'

  get 'posts' => 'posts#index'

  get 'posts/:id/edit' => 'posts#edit'
  put 'posts/:id' => 'posts#update'

  delete 'posts/:id' => 'posts#destroy'
end
```

Archivo index (muestra la tabla con todos los post)

```rb
<h1>Mostrar articulos</h1>
<%= link_to 'Nuevo post', :action => :new %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Titulo</th>
    <th>Texto</th>
  </tr>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.titulo %></td>
      <td><%= post.texto %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Mostrar', :action => :show, :id => post.id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Editar', :action => :edit, :id => post.id %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to 'Eliminar', { :action => :destroy, :id => post.id }, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => '¿Estas seguro?' } %>
      </td> 
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

El controlador

```rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @posts = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @posts = Post.new(post_param)

        if @posts.save
            redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @posts.id
        else
           render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    def edit
        @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @posts = Post.find(params[:id])

        if @posts.update(post_param)
            redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @posts.id
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
        @posts.destroy
        redirect_to :action => :index
    end

    private def post_param
        params.permit(:titulo, :texto)
    end
end
```

Comment: podrías intentar generar el link de esta manera? <%= link_to 'Eliminar', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: '¿Estas seguro?' } %> Qué version de rails estas utilizando? Cuando das click en *Eliminar* se levanta el confirm?

Comment: @h4k1 Al probar a generar el link tal y como me aconsejaste da un error: undefined local variable or method `post' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000c0a8>. La ventana del confirm no se levanto nunca